# Cannot access endpoints API from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using a chrome extension that calls the `chrome.identity` api to get an access token (using google plus login scope).

I then try to call a Google endpoints API with this token. For this, I set a request header with `'Authorization'='Bearer <token>'` format.

I have added the `client_id` from the `manifest.json` of my chrome extension to the list of allowed client ids for the endpoints API. But, I still cannot connect to it, even when I run the API on localhost.

The allowed list of client ids includes those clients that I defined on the API credentials page on Google Developers Console. My chrome extension is present as a client in that list, but it's client_id is different.

The error I keep getting on the server side:

```
WARNING  2016-04-22 03:01:35,068 users_id_token.py:372] Oauth token doesn't include an email address.
```

Can anyone please give me some pointers to try? Please let me know if any clarification is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Oauth2 APIs are commons of all types of clients, so i will answer in general which applies to all.

The google plus login scope(**plus.login** or **plus.me**) will not return email address, in order to get the authenticated user's email address you need to pass an additional scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email** which will returns users email address. Hope that is what you are looking for.

if you wants to experiment it, visit https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/